# Is the limit of this sequence Lipschitz-continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions, sequence-of-function

Suppose I have sequences $(f_{i,n})_n$  for $i=0,1,..,m$ of $M$-Lipschitz functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Each of those uniformly converges to an $M$-Lipschitz function $f_i$.
Now consider $F_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^k$ defined as $F_n(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^mv_if_{i,n}$ where $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ that converges uniformly to a function $F$.

Is $F$ Lipschitz-continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Notice that, for every $i = 0, \dots, m$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

\begin{align}
|f_{i,n}(x) - f_{i,n}(y)| &=
  |f_{i,n}(x)-f_{i}(x)| + |f_{i,n}(y)-f_{i}(y)| + |f_i(x)-f_i(y)|\\
  &\leq 2\|f_{i,n}-f_{i}\|_{\infty} + M|x-y|.
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{align}
|F(x)-F(y)| &= |F(x)-F_n(x)| + |F(y)-F_n(y)| + |F_n(x)-F_n(y)|\\
&\leq 2\|F-F_n\|_{\infty} + \sum_{i=0}^m |v_i| |f_{i,n}(x) - f_{i,n}(y)|\\
&\leq 2\|F-F_n\|_{\infty} + \sum_{i=0}^m |v_i| \Big(2\|f_{i,n}-f_{i}\|_{\infty} + M|x-y|\Big)\\
\end{align}

By uniform convergence, we have that
$\|F-F_n\|_{\infty}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ and $\|f_{i,n} - f_i\|_{\infty} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ for each $i$. Passing the above inequality to the limit we find that $F$ is Lipschitz.

Edit:
Notice that I haven't used the fact that the $f_{i,n}$ here are $M$-Lipschitz. Using this one can prove the second inequality directly:

\begin{align}
|F(x)-F(y)| &\leq 2\|F-F_n\|_{\infty} + \sum_{i=0}^m |v_i| |f_{i,n}(x) - f_{i,n}(y)|\\
&\leq 2\|F-F_n\|_{\infty} + \sum_{i=0}^m |v_i| M|x-y|\\
\end{align}

and then it suffices to use the uniform convergence of the $F_n$.